# Why do I get "Runtime Error" when I click "chat" on stackoverflow.com menu

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error 
using Windows IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

There was a bug in the main site API that caused chat to fail, and by the time that bug was fixed, one of the chat servers had been banned from the API because it had been retrying too often. So we had locked ourselves out :)

Comment: and I had hoped you had banned the IE9...